# C++ Debug - Instance counter

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

Is there a way to get a real time instance counter in visual studio in debug mode ? Like

```
Class Name | Number of instances
MyClass1   | 102
MyClass2   | 58
MyClass3   | 43
MyClass4   | 10
...
```

That would be refreshed every seconds.

Thanks !

Comment: Likely not. C++ does not maintain type information. The only information available is `n objects of 16 byte size`, `m objects of 24 byte size`.

Comment: This is already a good start. Is there any way to monitor this information please ?